# Form submit based on ajax response in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery and am preventing the submission of a form, then based on an ajax response will submit the form.  The problem I'm finding is that I often have to submit the form twice.  The first time, it shows the loader, but it doesn't get seem to call any actions within the ajax's success function.  If I click it a second time, it submits (if it's been validated).  It also seems to work the first time, after I go through this.  So if I try again, it'll work the first time.  So maybe it's a cache issue? Here's the javascript I have:

```
            $('#submit_zipcode_frm').submit(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var self = this;
                    $(".loader img").show();
                    z = $('#zipcode');
                    if(z.val() != '' && z.val().length == 5) {
                        var value = z.val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
                        var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
                        if(!intRegex.test(value)) {
                            $(".loader img").hide();
                            error($(".zipcode_field"));
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(".loader img").hide();
                        error($(".zipcode_field"));
                        return false;
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/ajax/save/zipcode", 
                        type: 'GET',
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data:   {zipcode: $('.zipcode_field').val()},
                        success: function(data) {
                                if(data == 'false'){
                                    $(".loader img").hide();
                                    error($(".zipcode_field"));
                                    return false;
                                }else{
                                    self.submit();
                                    getList();
                                }
                        }
                    });
            });
```

and here's the markup:

```
                        <form id="submit_zipcode_frm" class="submit_zipcode" method="post" action="/go" target="_blank">
                        <div class="zipcode_container">
                            <span class="loader">
                                <img src="/assets/img/loader.gif" style="display: none;"/>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="zip_input zipcode_field ghost" id="zipcode" name="zipcode"  value="Enter your Zip"/>
                            <div class="start_btn">
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        </form>
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be really appreciated.  Thank you!

EDIT:

Just to clarify the steps here:

1. User clicks the submit button
2. JavaScript show's the loader and validates the length and and type of the value entered
3. If that passes, an ajax lookup is used to truly validate it's a valid USPS zip code
4. If it is, the form is submitted and a function getList() is called
5. If it's not, error is thrown

Comment: Does `self.submit()` cause your submit handler to be called again?

Comment: @PaulGrime No, `formNode.submit()` will bypass any jQuery bound events. The return false shortly before however doesn't do anything, which is the root of the problem.